# How do I post a variable via ajax to a ruby script?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, http-post, twilio

This should be very simple I'm sure, but I'm a super newb. Basically, there is a website with a form field for a phone number, which will send a message to the phone number when user taps submit. (using Twilio)

javascript:

```
$("#phoneNumberButton").click(function(){
console.log( $("#styled").val());

var phoneNumberString = $("#styled").val();
phoneNumberString = phoneNumberString.replace(/\D/g,'');
if ( phoneNumberString.length != 10 ) {
     $('#styled').tooltipster('show');
} else {
$('#phoneNumberButton').text('Link sent!');
$.post( '_/ruby/TwilioSend.rb', {'phoneNumber': phoneNumberString} );
```

ruby ('_/ruby/TwilioSend.rb):

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = "xxxx" 
auth_token = "yyyy"   

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
message = @client.account.messages.create(:body => "Hello from Ruby",
:to => params[:phoneNumber],    # Replace with your phone number
:from => "+15555555555")  # Replace with your Twilio number

puts message.sid
```

The ruby file works when I execute it in terminal, with a static ':to' variable. But I can't get them working together. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure there are many things...fyi, that's all the ruby we use. there's no other ruby files. php was causing problems for us.

Answer (score 0):

The code that makes the call out to Twilio needs to be in a Rails controller. The Controller will have an associated route, for example:

```
# controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
    message = client.account.messages.create(:body => "Hello from Ruby", :to => params[:phoneNumber], :from => "+15555555555")

    render :json => { :sid => message.sid }
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
...
resources :messages
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you! I will definitely try that. When you say an associated route, do you mean i'm to set up a whole rails project? Or just create a routes.rb  post '_/ruby/messages_controller.rb', to: 'messages_controller#create'   ?

Comment: You are going to need some sort of web framework in order to receive the request from the AJAX. You could use Rails or something smaller such as Sinatra. You'll need to look into those frameworks and see what you think.